# Finding square roots of complex number with ruler and compass

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Provide the exact list of steps needed to find, with ruler and compass, the two square roots of a given complex number. (The points $0$ and $1$ are given)

---

I don't  really understand what I have to do in this question. We start off with the two numbers $0$ and $1$ and then we can choose our complex number? So the simplest one would be $i$.

But then what. I am very lost.

Comment: You don't get to choose your complex number. It's at some arbitrary point in the complex plane. Think about where its square root is in geometric terms, and find that square root with Euclidean tools.

Comment: @EthanBolker So if we are in a complex plane, lets draw a horizontal line and label 0 and 1 on this. Then the complex number $i$ would be somewhere above point 0 would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ Z = \sqrt{ r e^ {i \theta} } = \sqrt{ r}\cdot e^ {i \theta/2} $$

For the argument bisect the angle of given complex number using ruler/compass.

A unit length should be available on the ruler. Else there is another method.

Construct two line segments $PA,PB=r,1$ in a line along diameter of a circle. Draw the perpendicular at $P$ to find $ PN= \sqrt{ r}$.  Set off this length along bisected ray to find point representing sqrt of $Z$

EDIT 1:

The real and imginary parts of $x +i y $ are
$$ \frac{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{2}},$$

$$ \frac{-\sqrt{2} x \sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}}}{y}$$

and variants by sign change of radicals. But it cannot probably used as a method for such construction.

[image: To find SQRT]

Comment: Where exactly is P? Is this the origin of the circle? And where is N?

Comment: Two perpendicular lines cross at P. ( AP,NP,BP), AB is diameter.

Comment: Sorry I still cant figure out where N is... I see where P is now though.

Comment: shall put a sketch 5 mins

Comment: Please do, thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks so much, I am a bit confused why it says "two" square roots. Is the second one the line from P to the circumference?

Comment: One root is conjugate of other with sign of imaginary part  reversed.

Comment: How did you exactly know that NP is the square root of r?

Comment: Product of segment in a circle is constant... a property of cutting circle segments. Bye for now, cannot go in for a chat. hope ok..

Comment: I don't this is fully correct because we have to choose an arbitrary z that is just in random space...

Comment: You mean in 3D? your original post suggests complex numbers in a plane.